# Charger for lead-calcium battery circuit

Tags: electrical-engineering

I post it because I want to know if anyone of you see any error in this circuit made in proteus 8.6. I accept any observation, this circuit provide 12v of output and 3 modes of charging fast(15 A), medium(10 A) and slow(5 A).

[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you ask "if anyone of you see any rare in this circuit"? The word "rare" is out of place here. The question is not understandable as currently written.

Comment: When dV/dt = Ic/C  what use is C1?  This design fails in so many ways. No design specs for electrical, thermal and tolerances, feedback for each current limiter on voltage, no temperature compensated voltage regulation,  Please advise.